# How to authenticate a user in es6 while data coming from API?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have an API which is working fine on Postman and getting a result when I provided the email and password in the header section ,now I have a login form and I want to authenticate the user from that API data result if the user name and password matched with API data then logged in otherwise show error. This type of work I wanted but I am very confused where to start it.and I only want to use es6 functions.

Answer (score 1):

You create a `login` function that makes an ajax call to your API, probably using the `fetch` API (or some other ajax library like `Axios`). Your call returns a promise, with the result from the server, which you then act upon.

```js
const login = (formValues) => {
  return fetch('/your/api/url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(formValues)
  })
  .then((response) => JSON.parse(response))
  .then((data) => {
    // do something with the server data
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // do something with the error
  });
};
```

That's the gist. Your server may require additional request parameters, so review the API for whatever ajax method you choose. Again, there are libraries like `Axios` that can abstract/simplify/expand the `fetch` API for you, or you can just use it directly. Biggest thing to remember is that you can't access the return values until you actually have them, so if you are unfamiliar with Promises then you should also study up on them.

[Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)